How do I get the currently playing song title from SoundCloud using MPNowPlayingInfo
I am developing a SwiftUI application and I am having the hardest time (as in I have been completely unable) to get meta data from SoundCloud. The SoundCloud app is populating control center with the metadata so I should be able to access it.
I am able to get the metadata from Apple Music for example using  let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer. Any 3rd party app need to be using: let nowPlayingInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo.
I have added the permissions for Media Library access and Apple Music.
I just need to know if it is possible as technically it should be. All the posts concerning it are from iOS 6 or 11 years ago. Any help would be much appreciated.
import MediaPlayer

class NowPlayingMetadataObserver: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songTitle: String = "Unknown Title"
    @Published var artistName: String = "Unknown Artist"
    @Published var albumTitle: String = "Unknown Album"

    init() {
        // OBSERVE CHANGES IN NOW PLAYING
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(handleNowPlayingInfoChange),
            name: NSNotification.Name.MPNowPlayingInfoCenterNowPlayingInfoDidChange,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    @objc private func handleNowPlayingInfoChange() {
        if let nowPlayingInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo {
            songTitle = nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String ?? "Unknown Title"
            artistName = nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String ?? "Unknown Artist"
            albumTitle = nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String ?? "Unknown Album"
        } else {
            songTitle = "No song playing"
            artistName = "Unknown Artist"
            albumTitle = "Unknown Album"
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
    
    
// DISPLAY THE RESULT WHEN 3RD PARTY APP IS PLAYING
struct ContentView: View { 
    @StateObject private var metadataObserver = NowPlayingMetadataObserver()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Now Playing:")
                .font(.headline)
    
            Text(metadataObserver.songTitle)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
    
            Text("Artist: \(metadataObserver.artistName)")
                .font(.subheadline)
    
            Text("Album: \(metadataObserver.albumTitle)")
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

